# SSRS cached reports with parameters use only first generated one

Tags: reporting-services

We have a report taking in parameter a country ID. This report a really slow to render so we decided to add some caching.

[image]

However, when running the report, regardless the value I provide, it will always render the first cache version produced (in my case, always the 65/france one, I guess because first in the cache plan list). When I disable the cache, then parameter is correctly taken into account (so not a report problem)

[image]

I am missing something ? according to documentation, for each combination of parameters, a cache version should exists...

below configuration of report for data processing
[image]

Comment: How are the parameters being set in the client? Is there a default value? Could something on the client side have cached the default parameter as France from earlier runs? alas, are you saying when you implicitly select another country and set the country parameter, France is always being used?

Comment: The report has no default value (so it's not a fallback due to missing parameter). Parameter is filled in through standard UI (http://i.imgur.com/JCGXlIM.png). I can put any number as parameter (in the textbox), will always be France) ...

Comment: hmmm, did you add the parameter after the cache plan was established?

Comment: just waited for another cache refresh (every 5 hours) to be sure parameters taken into account. we can see the number of rows which is different per country (expected). http://i.imgur.com/NDY6IcI.png still always rendering the data of the first cache refresh (this time ID=5 with 142 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation and Microsoft premiere help (without success), appeared that the stored procedure input field was type string and declared as integer in rdl file. This mismatch seems not correctly handled by cache.

I didn't had the confirmation from MS engineer that it was a bug or by design.